# Agrupar items de un array en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un array con valores de horas la cuales, las presento en una etiqueta select de la siguiente manera:

**Select**

```
07:00:00
07:10:00
07:20:00
07:30:00
07:40:00
07:50:00
08:00:00
```

Pero deseo saber como agruparlos de la siguiente manera:

```
07:00:00 - 07:10:00
07:10:00 - 07:20:00
07:20:00 - 07:30:00
07:30:00 - 07:40:00
07:40:00 - 07:50:00
07:50:00 - 08:00:00
```

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="data.rh"
          ng-init="data.rh=rangoHoras[0].h"
          ng-options="rh.h as rh.h for rh in rangoHoras"
          style="color:#283593;">
  </select>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.rangoHoras=[
        {"h":"07:00:00"},{"h":"07:10:00"},{"h":"07:20:00"},
        {"h":"07:30:00"},{"h":"07:40:00"},{"h":"07:50:00"},
        {"h":"08:00:00"}
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer un metodo que sirva como filtro para regresar los horarios de la manera que buscas.

```
$scope.generarRangoHoras =function() {
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<$scope.rangoHoras.length-1; i++){
      tmp.push({
        h:$scope.rangoHoras[i].h+ " - "+ $scope.rangoHoras[i+1].h
      });      
    }
    return tmp;
 }
```

Y el select queda de la siguiente forma

```
 <select ng-options="rh.h as rh.h for rh in generarRangoHoras()" ng-model="seleccionado"/>
```

Ejemplo:

http://codepen.io/DKbyo/pen/GqYwQb

Comment: Gracias amigo muy buen aporte